# Groovy Imap Access

Tags: java, groovy, jakarta-mail

I have following code

```
import javax.mail.*

def host = "imap.gmail.com"
def port = "993"
def username = "username@gmail.com"
def password = "password"

Properties props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap")
props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", host)
props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", port)
def session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
def store = session.getStore("imap")

store.connect(host, username, password)
def folder = store.getFolder("INBOX")
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)
folder.messages.each { msg ->
    println msg.subject
}
```

but when I run this script it just hangs after compilation. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With gmail we have to enforce SSL. to do this I just added

```
props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

and that fixed the problem

Edit:

A better solution will be to do:

```
props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
```

Thanks @Bill Shannon to point that.

Comment: [Don't do that.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)  Set the property "mail.imap.ssl.enable" to "true".